# How to get data from tableview cell without showing on label using Swift?

Tags: swift, tableview

My Scenario, I am trying to create `tableview` cell click to get `label` data also I have more `values` but I don’t want to show in `label`. Now, how can I `assign` `unshowed` data into `cell`, because I am `sending` values to another `view controller` after cell `didselect`.

For Example:

I have two array values

```
 let alpha: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
 let numeric: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Here, I am sowing only alpha values into tableview cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell
    cell.textlabel.text = alpha[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Now, I am going to get tableview cell selected values, Here, I can able to get cell.textlabel.text value but I need to get numeric values also without assign any labels.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as? MyCustomCell
     print(currentCell?.textlabel?.text ?? "unknown alpha")

     // Here I need to get numeric values also 
}
```

Comment: In `didSelectRowAt` is the same parameter as in `cellForRowAt`: `indexPath` ... `let numbericValue = numeric[indexPath.row]`

Comment: What do you mean with "persist"? You can always get it from your dataSource array with `numeric[indexPath.row]` like Robert wrote

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can get unshowed cell index array values by using below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as? MyCustomCell
        print(currentCell?.myCellLabel?.text ?? "unknown")

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailview") as! DetailViewController
        newViewController.name = currentCell?.myCellLabel?.text ?? "unknown"
        newViewController.country = self.numeric[indexPath.row]
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```